# Using "this" in setters

Tags: java

I see no real difference between the following two methods of creating a setter, but was wondering if I am just naive. Is one more desirable than the other?

```
public void fooSetter(String bar)
{
    _bar = bar;
}


public void fooSetter(String bar)
{
    this._bar = bar;
}
```

Comment: your fields should not start with underscore. While this is debatable, it may cause problems with frameworks that manipulate the pojo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no semantic difference in this case because there is no ambiguity. If, on the other hand, your instance field was also called `bar` then `this` would be required to disambiguate:

```
public void fooSetter(String bar)
{
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

Comment: Worth saying that the underscore in `_bar` is not conventional for private member variables in Java - usually just `bar`.

Comment: Correct, _bar is not conventional, but it seems more compact than m_bar and the meaning still appears to be clear.

Comment: @Noel M: That's true. Of course, the core API seems to love single-letter parameters for setter methods, too. =/

Comment: But why m_bar? Why not just 'bar'? All this _bar m_bar stuff is a relic of C++, where it is needed. Not required in Java.

Answer (score 7):

You do not need "this" since there is no ambiguity.  ("bar" and "_bar" are different.  now if your field was called "bar" as well, you'd need it)

Comment: `this` is just not to disambiguate - just to be explicit for referencing variables of that instance. I tend to use it even with there is no need to disambiguate

Comment: @Noel: Isn't the underscore coding convention enough? I seriously hate superfluous `this` keywords :P

Comment: Underscore is **not** convention in Java

Comment: @Noel: Nope, but if someone is using it, using `this` as well makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Thorarin using what? `this`? It's a keyword, you can't use it for anything else.

Comment: He's saying if someone is using the underscore, using this as well doesn't make sense to him.

Answer (score 4):

The different styles are mostly caused by what a programmer did before Java, what coding standards are present in the company, etc.

The desired style is to use:

```
    public class A {
          private Type property;

          public Type getProperty(){
              return this.property;
          }

          public void setProperty(Type property){
              this.property = property;
          }
    }
```

This is kind of the best-practice style and complies to the [JavaBeans](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) standard.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using setters in Java, `this` can be helpful to escape the current variable scope.  If you instead had

```
private String bar = "";

public void fooSetter(String bar){
  this.bar = bar
}
```

That would correctly set the class variable instead of that function variable

Answer (score 2):

> Is one more desirable than the other?

Depends on the scope you want to use-

```
public class myClass{

    private int number=5;

    private void setNumbers(float number){
        number=1; // refers to local variable (float)
        this.number=2; // refers to class variable (int)
    }

}
```

I like to use "this.variable" whenever I refer to a class variable, you'll note that Eclipse will also highlight class variables in blue where local variables stay black which can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second way, just because it makes it clear to the reader and it's consistent since it's needed when the the parameter and field are both named the same (when it is necessary so as to differentiate what is being set). There is no functional difference between the two in this example, though.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is explicit and for that reason is preferred by many. In some cases the difference is significant, however. e.g. a member variable and local variable of the same name.

```
public void fooSetter(String bar)
{
    String _bar = fancyfilter(bar);
    this._bar = _bar;
}
```

A somewhat contrived example, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

your setters should be

```
setFoo(String foo)
```

and

```
public String getFoo()
```

to conform to javabean conventions.

If the reference name in the setter (foo) is the same as the property on the class, then you should use 'this' to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, it is disambiguous, but I prefer without using **this** as well.

I would go with something like this which also prevents ambiguity by giving names more explicit to the variables purpose.

```
public void setBar(String newBar)
{
    bar = newBar;
}
```

This would be my first choice, the second would be to use the **this**, I wouldn't consider the underscores.